# Numerical methods. MDF (ILU) implementation

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization, krylov-method

I am trying to implement **Minimum Discarded Fill (MDF) Ordering algorithm** for incomplete matrix factorization. The algorithm description is here on page 60 [Preconditioning Techniques for a Newton–Krylov Algorithm
for the Compressible Navier–Stokes Equations](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/43576/6/Gatsis_John_201311_PhD_thesis.pdf).

There is a thing that I don't understand. For initialization I should use Algorithm 7 (page 62)

> Compute the discard value for all nodes vj in the graph of A0 using Algorithm 7

But this algorithm uses the value that is calculated later. We have only variables with k-index

> Compute the discard value, discard(vk) = ||Fk||F using the following iterations

And there is the k+1-index variable

> lev(k+1)

I can’t understand whether it is a recursion or something regarding iterative methods... if it will be easy for anyone to understand this MDF algorithm, please tell me how to implement this moment.